# remove all label with a Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I deleted all of node and relationship. Now, I want to **delete all existing labels** with a Cypher query but I can't.

Comment: I think this is impossible in current version of Neo4j's browser,

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the neo4j browser's "Node labels" display. The browser can continue to display labels that have been deleted from all nodes (or even if the DB no longer has any nodes). This is really just a minor nuisance.

As long as your Cypher queries show that there are no nodes with that label, rest assured that the label does not "really" exist in the DB.

Comment: I think it is a bug of Neo4j's browser. It show all label include label that don't used or remove all of nodes and relationships.

Answer (score -1):

If you're removing all of the data (nodes and relationships) anyway, you might as well delete your graph.db directory or wherever you store your data. This will also result in having pre-existing labels not show up in the browser.

This will also remove all indexes you might have had set up.